# Pumping lemma occurrence of c > d

Tags: computability, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove a language is not regular through using pumping lemma, but can't seem to come up with any way of doing it.

The alphabet is:

$$ \Sigma = \{c, d\} $$

The language is:

$$ A = \{z \in \Sigma^* \mid c(z) > d(z)\} , \text{where $c(w)$ and $d(w)$ means occurrences of $c$ or $d\in z$  }$$

I tried to define a string like so:

Pumping length = P

$$ s = c^{(P+1)}d^P $$

Here is how I tried to solve it:

If we select P = 5. Then s = ccccccddddd and split it in 3 parts. Where x = ccccccd, y = ddd and z = d. (Is that even allowed though as |xy| <= P, but now |xy|=10 and 10>5). If I then do y^2. Then I get s = ccccccdddddddd, so now d>c which proves the string is not in the language. Does this then prove that the language is not regular?

Comment: I suggest you keep trying.

Comment: Have been stuck for quite some time so I don't think that will help. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: You won’t understand the material if other people solve all exercises for you. This is a relatively simple application of the pumping lemma, so it’s there to help you practice the basics.

Comment: Yes I do know this is probably basics, but I would like an answer that I then could look back on when solving the other exercises in the future. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: I seems you are on the right track, but try to switch the order of $c$'s and $d$'s in your string, so $s = d^p c^{p+1}$.

Comment: I believe the hint given by @Acid just solves the half of the problem. Remember that, while splitting the word into xyz, |xy| <= pumping length

Comment: Okay do you think my solution is valid or do I need to do something different? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: I tried doing solving it but don't know if the solution is valid. What do you think? @AcId

Comment: I tried doing solving it but don't know if the solution is valid. What do you think? @SiluPanda

Comment: You cannot select $P$ - it is just a number that we know exists - and you cannot make any assumptions about $x$, $y$, $z$ other than that they satisfy the three conditions of the Pumping Lemma.

Comment: Okay, I saw I guy on youtube who did it. If that is the case then I'm clueless. @AcId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that with that arbitrary pumping length $P$, for **any** partition $c^{(P+1)}d^P = xyz$ such that $|y|>0$ and $|xy|\leq P$, there is some $i$ such that $xy^iz \not\in A$.

Since for any partition we require that $|xy|\leq P$, then $x$ and $y$ necessarily consist only of $c$'s. Also, you know that $|y| >0$ (it's also a requirement). Can you find an $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the amount of $c$'s in $xy^iz$ is less than or equal to the amount of $d$'s?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a string that's in the language (i.e., has fewer $d$s than $c$s) but, when pumped, creates strings that are not in the language (more $d$s than $c$s). Think about how you can achieve that.

Comment: Okay I tried to solve it. Do you think the solution I did above is valid or am I missing something?

Comment: @Android999 you can't claim to know what $p$ is, nor can you define $x$, $y$, or $z$. The answer is given here. Carefully review the laws of the lemma and make sure you understand this answer

Comment: @Android999 That's not quite right, for the reasons that lox points out and because we require $|xy|\leq P$. But the language is strings of $c$s and $d$s in any order, which mean you can choose a similar $s$ which makes your life easier. Or you could choose a different number of repetitions for $y$, which can also be made to work.